# Override !important on width attribute?

Tags: css, leaflet

I have some external css styles, and one of them adds this rule:

```
svg {
    width: 100% !important
}
```

This seems to override my `width` attribute (when inspecting in chrome DevTools). The thing is that it overrides the width from a div element that's generated by a javascript plugin (Leaflet) which expands a given div to have this a an element (a svg element with a 3 lines in it).

```
<svg class="leaflet-zoom-animated" width="1442" height="728" viewBox="-722 -364 1442 728" style="transform: translate3d(-722px, -364px, 0px);">
    <g>
        <path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" pointer-events="none" stroke="green" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="5" fill="none" d="M-584 -109L-252 64"></path>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" pointer-events="none" stroke="green" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="5" fill="none" d="M-222 167L-252 64"></path>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" pointer-events="none" stroke="green" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="5" fill="none" d="M34 -338L-252 64"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

The width is needed to display the Leaflet map, and currently it seems to collapse to 0px by 0px (the parent node has no size either, which is fine though).

Is there any way I can make sure the element still gets the width that is set by the Leaflet plugin, and that it's not being overriden?

Comment: No way. `!important` has the highest priority even higher than inline style.

Comment: @LeoDeng - Not higher than inline style with `!important`

Comment: The style rule you are providing wouldn't override some other div's width, especially since it's not a child of the svg. The div probably is collapsing because it has no content inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny enough, we can make Chrome, Opera and Firefox respect the width attribute by setting the width to `auto` with a more specific selector. Not Internet Explorer.

As rightly pointed out in the comments, the `!important` has the highest specificity, it can be overwritten only by a more specific `!important`. In this case, you can set the width to `auto` to those svg elements that have `leaflet` part in their class name, for instance like so:

```
svg[class|=leaflet] {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

It doesn't really matter if you add this rule before or after that external css file. Both will work.

You can find more about attribute selectors in [Chris's post](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/) or other places.

**No IE support though!** I'm not sure who does it right in this case, but the fact remains. A live example can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/na4sdxnk/

Comment: This works great (on chrome at least). I was aware that it could be overridden by a more specific rule, but setting it to auto is the crucial step to get the browser to respect the original attribute `width` again!

Answer (score 1):

I think i got your question correct.can we add the svg inside the div container and give that svg an attribute with the !important.With that it will override the one which applies globallay and listens to the one specific to the svg inside the div.

http://jsfiddle.net/hw60vs5a/

```
svg{
    background-color:lightgrey !important;
    width:100% !important;
}

div svg{
    background-color:lightblue !important;
    width:auto !important;
}
```

*Note: I am not much aware of how svg works*